# Run same piece of code when injecting an angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to run the same line of code to each function a specific service is injected. For instance:

```
app.service('sameInitService', function ($rootScope) {
  this.init = function (scope) {
    scope.foo = $rootScope.foo;
  }
});

app.controller('oneController', function ($scope, sameInitService) {
  sameInitService.init($scope); // <- This line of code
});

app.controller('twoController', function ($scope, sameInitService) {
  sameInitService.init($scope); // <- Is the same
});
```

Is there an angular-ish way to avoid having to write the same line of code when this service is injected?

Comment: services are singletons, so the use cases for needing to do this are limited;  can you explain a bit more about what it is you are trying to accomplish here and why every controller has to call the same code block?

Comment: I've attached an object on $rootScope that contains translation strings for the application. I want to be able to access that object on templates using the exact same syntax. Eg:

    {{translationObject.Path.To.My.String}}

This won't work on **components** because they don't have direct access to $rootScope. I know i can use:

    {{$root.translationObject.Path.To.My.String}}

but I do not want to for a specific reason. The production build process uses regexes to replace the angular expressions with the translations, so I need to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: this is a poor way to design your service, and prone to failure.  Services are singletons, and the moment that you change the value in the service, you are changing it for every controller that has this injected.  it may *seem* like this is working properly, mainly because all the controllers share the same `$rootScope`, but it definitely is a path that leads to danger.

Comment: Why are you even using `$rootScope` at all in conjunction with a service?  Why can't the service itself hold the object, and just use `$scope.translationObject = translationService.Object`?

Comment: @Claies Making the value change across all controllers is exactly the behavior I want. The reason I use on rootScope is because I want the translation keys available globally in templates, even in templates that do not have a controller with the service injected

Comment: you still seem to be describing a not well planned design. (no offense meant).  If there is *any chance* that a specific controller might set this `$rootScope` value to something different than what every other controller would, then how does refactoring it so that every controller issues the same command help? and if there is *no chance*  that one controller would change the settings affecting every other controller, than every controller running this doesn't make sense.

Comment: if this is *really* something that has to be global, and on `$rootScope`, then it should be set at the entry point of your app and then never changed ever again.

Comment: Ok let me try to explain the problem a bit more.

1) The only reason of existence for this global object is to be accessed by templates, to provide strings that change depending on the selected language.

2) The reason i need to access these strings using a single format (eg {{translations.Path.To.Key}} is because of the production build process, which uses regexes to find those and replace them.

3) The problem is with **components** which will not inherit rootScope variables, so i need to do this "hack" to keep it consistent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by decorating the $controller service but in this case all your controllers will be initialized this way.

```
angular.module('App', [])
  .config(['$provide', function($provide) {

    $provide.decorator('$controller', [
      '$delegate', 'sameInitService',
      function controllerDecorator($delegate, sameInitService) {

        return function(constructor, locals) {
          sameInitService.init(locals.$scope);
          return $delegate(constructor, locals, true);
        }
      }

    ]);
  }])
```

See jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x4tpdy5z/2/).

Comment: Thanks for your lead on the decorators, I posted an answer based on your code that completely solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

I want to extend on @janusz 's answer and present the code that I actually ended up using, which takes care of the "apply behavior only to controllers with injected dependency":

```
angular.module('App').decorator('$controller', function ($delegate, sameInitService) {
    return function (constructor, locals) {
        var controller = $delegate.apply(null, arguments);
        return angular.extend(function () {
          var controllerInstance = controller()
          var DIList = controllerInstance .__proto__.constructor.$inject;
          console.log(DIList);
          if (DIList.indexOf('sameInitService') !== -1) {
            sameInitService.init(locals.$scope);
          }
          return controllerInstance;
        }, controller);
    };
});
```

Here is a modified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x4tpdy5z/6/)